# How to run photoshop closed?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, javascript

Is it possible to run photoshop without running it? I want to run an action that basically replaces image layers and text layers, and quick exports results.

Summing up, I have come to know about Javascript API action doAction, but how do I run that without turning on Photoshop?

Comment: It would probably have to open Photoshop, though you can use certain tools to hide it from the foreground.

Comment: but as @jooja said, resources will still be used as much with gui hidden, i am trying to speedup our routine process but photoshop really affects the overall work output

Answer (score 1):

You don't. If you use a Photoshop api call it starts Photoshop. Yeah sure you get a option to not show the window, but Photoshop is still using resources just as is the window would just be hidden.

Comment: so you're saying there is possibly no way to pass an API  request without having to run the photoshop?

Comment: @Zuhaib No theres no way to do this without implementing something that is photoshop but is not photoshop. Siftware has to run inorder for you to do something, in this case that something is photoshop.

Comment: I guess Adobe would have to add this as a feature, and they likely won't... consider using Gimp.

Comment: @WELZ Well they really  can not. Inorder for them to be able to run all features of photoshop they need a application that is photosop like enough to qualify. Why on eart would they re implement a software they already have. I mean sure you could do a subset of things you can do on photoshop without phostoshop but then why use photoshop features. Something has to run, the richer more like photoshop you want it to be the more likely the only alternative is that its photoshop

Comment: thank you guys tho ^_^ this is my first post here. 
ill look into Gimp as well.

Comment: @Zuhaib its nit like gimp scripting can run without gimp either.

Comment: @Zuhaib you probably want to start using imagemagic

Comment: pass a parameter run the action, >< i guess autohotkey has got the better part of my logic,
although i do think something could be done

Comment: @Zuhaib yes offcourse whatever you do can be done, but thne you must accept your not using photoshop. Then you dont benefit form your photoshop skills

Comment: @joojaa i was already looking into Imagemajick, i cant seem to find an option to replace image layer with another image yet.

Comment: @Zuhaib well ofccourse not since imagemagic does not operate on pshotoshop files. Anyway you can do this with photoshop without opening photoshop by using linked files. Just replace the file with another file done. Next time you open photoshop its changed

Comment: @Zuhaib anyway your looking at this the worng way, it really does not matter how long it takes for the scipt to run. Its still A) faster than doing it manually. B) Your computer sint being used 24/7 so your computer can do all these things in the backgtound while you sleep. C) If you really need to speed it up just run a second computer to do these for you. D) Or ditch photoshop